# Realms in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

I actually started playing minecraft 2 month ago and in the xbox app I am in a group of minecraft players that only play "realm".

I actually don't understand what realms are? Can I play it in minecraft v1.8.0? Should I purchase them or are they for free?

Comment: https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1018151-minecraft-realms a quick google :)

Answer (score 0):

Please post only **1** [question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).

A quick google search is able to explain the question much better than we can answer here.

Yes - Realms currently works for 1.8.0 Bedrock Edition, and yes, they have a monthly subscription fee.

Find out more [here](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1018151-minecraft-realms).

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft realms has a monthly fee and is not free. What realms does is it makes you Minecraft realm world available to other people with the realm code while you are offline. Max players online your realm is ten or two depending on what plan you choose however there is no max share limit. If you do happen to buy a realm your friends can play on it for free with no charge. So with a lot of friends you can all pool some money to buy you own personal realm.

> NOTE: two player max realm costs $3.99 USD. Ten players max realm costs $7.99 USD

Answer (score 0):

A minecraft realm is like a multiplayer server, they have a monthly subscription fee and they don't require any mods, and I'm pretty sure you can play them in 1.8